# Test Automapper return collection or not

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, automapper

I am testing one of my services - movieService. GetLatestMovies method should return all movies, ordered by date. I am using automapper to map the entity Movie to MovieViewModel.

*** Question 1: *** How am I supposed to test that, should I set the return collection in the test or what?

*** Question 2: *** I am filling the InMemory database with a few movies and I am expecting correct ordered result from the movieService, how am I supposed to check, If the service is returning correct result, If I set the return from the automapper?

TestUtils.FillContextWithActorsMoviesAndGenres(options) - just fills the context with a few movies.

This is the movieService method I am testing

```
public async Task<ICollection<MovieViewModel>> GetLatestMoviesAsync()
        {
            var movies = await this.context.Movies
                .Include(um => um.ApplicationUserMovie)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.User)
                .Include(x => x.Genre)
                .Include(x => x.MovieActor)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Actor)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).ToListAsync();

            var returnMovies = this.mappingProvider.MapTo<ICollection<MovieViewModel>>(movies);

            return returnMovies;
        }
```

```
[TestMethod]
        public async Task Return_TwoMoviesWithHighestRating()
        {
            var dabataseName = nameof(Return_TwoMoviesWithHighestRating);

            var options = TestUtils.GetOptions(dabataseName);

            // We fill the context with data and save it.
            TestUtils.FillContextWithActorsMoviesAndGenres(options);


            var movieOne = new MovieViewModel()
            {
                Name = "BestRatedMovieTest",
                Duration = 90,
                Director = "TestDirector",
                Storyline = "TestStoryline",
                ImageUrl = "TestImageUrl",
                Genre = "Comedy"
            };

            var movieTwo = new MovieViewModel()
            {
                Name = "SecondMovieTestName",
                Duration = 90,
                Director = "TestDirector",
                Storyline = "TestStoryline",
                ImageUrl = "TestImageUrl",
                Genre = "Comedy"
            };

            var collectionMovieViewModels = new List<MovieViewModel>() { movieOne, movieTwo };


            var mappingProviderMock = new Mock<IMappingProvider>();
            mappingProviderMock
                .Setup(x => x.MapTo<ICollection<MovieViewModel>>(It.IsAny<List<Movie>>()))
                .Returns(collectionMovieViewModels);


            using (var actAndAssertContext = new MovieManagementContext(options))
            {
                var sut = new MovieService(actAndAssertContext, mappingProviderMock.Object);
                var movies = await sut.GetLatestMoviesAsync();

                Assert.AreEqual(2, movies.Count());
                Assert.AreEqual("BestRatedMovieTest", movies.FirstOrDefault().Name);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an empty collection and set the Callback of the method to fill that collection,

```
var collectionOfMovies = new List<Movie>();

var mappingProviderMock = new Mock<IMappingProvider>();
            mappingProviderMock
                .Setup(x => x.MapTo<ICollection<MovieViewModel>>(It.IsAny<List<Movie>>()))
                .Callback<object>(inputargs => collectionOfMovies = inputargs as List<Movie>);
```